# the getter _widget şsn't defined for the class

Tags: flutter, dart

/D:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:932:19: Error: The getter '_widget' isn't defined for the class 'State'.

- 'State' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/D:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  framework.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named '_widget'.

  T get widget => _widget!;

what is this error i didn't see any anwser on the internet I tried clean pub get but didn't work.